# Cloud Formation function doesn't assign value to value for key within a Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I have the following Cloud Formation template to create a VPC. The VPC name is generated based off of the region and the environment that the template was created in. The VPC creates without any issues, and running `aws cloud formation validate-template --template-url https://foo.template` doesn't complaing about any of the syntax.

I would expect the VPC to be named:

> vpc-uw1-d-fs

What happens instead is the VPC is left with an empty name and the Name tag has an empty value. Am I not using the function correctly? If I remove the `Fn::FindInMap` function usage, I get the name generated - it's just missing the environment mapped value.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "VPC for a new environment to use.",
    "Parameters": {
        "EnvironmentName": {
            "Description": "Name of the environment that this VPC will be used for.",
            "Type": "String",
            "MinLength": "2",
            "MaxLength": "20",
            "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z]*",
            "AllowedValues": [
                "Development",
                "QA",
                "Test",
                "Production"
            ]
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "VPC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC",
            "Properties": {
                "CidrBlock": "10.0.0.0/16",
                "EnableDnsSupport": false,
                "EnableDnsHostnames": false,
                "InstanceTenancy": "default",
                "Tags": [ { 
                    "Key": "Name",
                    "Value": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "-",
                            [
                                "vpc",
                                { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
                                { "Fn::FindInMap": [
                                    "EnvironmentMap", { "Ref": "EnvironmentName" }, "AbbreviatedName"
                                ]},
                                "fs"
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "Mappings": {
        "RegionMap": {
            "us-east-1": {
                "regionName": "ue1"
            },
            "us-west-1": {
                "regionName": "uw1"
            }
        },
        "EnvironmentMap": {
            "Development": { 
                "AbbreviatedName": "d"
            },
            "QA": { 
                "AbbreviatedName": "qa"
            },
            "Test": { 
                "AbbreviatedName": "t"
            },
            "Production": { 
                "AbbreviatedName": "p"
            }
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template is working perfectly fine for me.

I ran it in the `ap-southeast-2` region and it produced the tag:

- **Name:** `vpc-ap-southeast-2-d-fs`

(The `RegionMap` is not used in the template given.)

Comment: Thanks, it works for me now as well. Perhaps my upload of the modified template to S3 didn't happen like I thought it did. That `RegionMap` will eventually be used to replace the `{ "Ref": "AWS::Region" } with a `Fn::FindInMap` to pull the abbreviated region name out.